# git: How to checkout specific (latest) version on a specific submodule (using git submodule ...)

Tags: git, git-submodules

So I have a repo with a bunch of submodules in it. I only want to update one of them, but I want to update to the latest commit which I know is at the tip of branch called origin/mybranch. The submodule I want to update is mysubmodule (for example)

First I tried this:

```
git submodule update --remote -- mysubmodule
```

This was a bit of a disaster in that it seemed to checkout the latest origin/master branch (which is way old).

So I read some of the git docs, this seems to be the default behaviour - fair enough!

But how do I checkout the remote commit that has the branch origin/mybranch?

I tried things like:

```
git submodule update --remote --checkout mybranch -- mysubmodule 
git submodule update --remote --checkout origin/mybranch -- mysubmodule
```

But I have not managed to figure this out yet :(

Comment: Try `cd mysubmodule;git checkout origin/mybranch`.

Comment: @ElpieKay ah, I excplicitly want to do it with `git sumbodule ... `. I know that I can cd into the submodule and do normal git commands : )

Comment: `git submodule` doesn't have such a command. And why should it, if you can just `cd` into the dir and run `git` there?

Comment: @NilsWerner I am running a batch processing function which runs a single command at the top level of each project. So I want a command that can update my submodule from the top-level of the project... that is why it should .. just for me : ))  ... but if its not possible, then that is a perfectly valid answer

Comment: @code_fodder As using cd is not a good practice in a script, you could use `git --git-dir=mysubmodule/.git checkout origin/mybranch` from the top-level of the project.

Comment: Use `--git-dir` or run it in a subshell: `(cd submodule ; git ...)`. The next line will be back in the cwd.

Comment: @ElpieKay awesome!, thanks - please add as an answer I will mark it up :)

Comment: @NilsWerner This also looks viable, so please also add as an answer and I will upvote it : )

Comment: Note that there is also `git submodule foreach`, which takes a shell command to run and does a `cd` into each submodule and runs that command. But if you only want to work on *one* submodule, you don't want to use `foreach`.

Comment: @torek yeah, I did have a little play with `foreach`, but as you say - it works on all submodules :o

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `branch` option for your submodule in order to track the submodule branch you want to be up to date to. This implies a change in the `.gitmodules` file.

```
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.<path>.branch <branch>
```

E.g.

```
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.mysubmodule.branch mybranch
```

Once you've set this up, next time you run `git submodule update --remote...`, in the submodule git will checkout the commit your branch points to (the latest commit on your branch).
This can be set up when adding a submodule:

```
git submodule add -b <branch> <repository> [<path>]
```